# Stored Procedure Output Parameter null value

Tags: ado.net

I tried to call a stored procedure using `SqlCommand` with output parameters. The call is successfully made and I got the result back.

My problem occurs after getting the result when I tried to access value from the output parameter fails sporadically with

1. Object Reference exception
2. `SqlParameter` with the parameter name is not contained in the collection
3. Conversion from "" string to int failed.

Note this not happening all the time , sometimes it does and sometimes it doesn't (sporadically occurs which makes it very hard to find the cause).

This is happening only in our prod environment (dev and test couldn't recreate it).

EX:

```
With _objCmd
     .CommandText = "MyStoredProcName"
     .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
     .Parameters.Add("@p_status", SqlDbType.Int).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
     .Parameters.Add("@p_msg", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
     .Parameters.Add("@p_searchusing", SqlDbType.NVarChar, -1).Value = BlankToNull(SearchDrugUsing)
End With

// my code execution happens here and returns results
_retcode = CType(String.Concat(_objCmd.Parameters("@p_status").Value, ""), Integer)
_retmsg = CType(String.Concat(_objCmd.Parameters("@p_msg").Value, ""), String)
```

Note : using `SqlDataAdapter` and fill method to map the stored procedure result and try to access output parameter from `SqlCommand`.

When I comment the output parameter code lines.. its not occurring at all...

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: That doesn't look like **C# 4.0** to me .....

Answer (score 0):

Never mind i was able to fix this issue. Its related to the scope leak of access variable (sqlcommand) as it was declared shared variable. So when more and more thread comes to access the sqlcommand object it throws exception sporadically. Make it unique fixes everything.